# Numbering of auxiliary symbols in AceGen generated code

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I have a general question regarding the numbering of auxiliary symbols in AceGen.
Consider this example (taken from the AceGen manual, only the language is switched to `C++`):

```
<< AceGen`
SMSInitialize["test", "Language" -> "C++"];
SMSModule["Test", Real[u$$[3], x$$, L$$, g$$[3]]];
x \[RightTee] SMSReal[x$$];
L \[RightTee] SMSReal[L$$];
ui \[RightTee] SMSReal[Table[u$$[i]  , {i, 3}]];
Ni \[DoubleRightTee] {x/L, 1 - x/L, x/L*(1 - x/L)};
u \[DoubleRightTee] Ni . ui;
f \[DoubleRightTee] u^2;
g \[DoubleRightTee] SMSD[f, ui];
SMSExport[g, g$$];
SMSWrite[];
```

Which generates the following code:

```
void Test(double v[125],double u[3],double (*x),double (*L)
     ,double g[3])
{
v[6]=(*x)/(*L);
v[7]=1e0-v[6];
v[8]=v[6]*v[7];
v[15]=2e0*(u[0]*v[6]+u[1]*v[7]+u[2]*v[8]);
g[0]=v[15]*v[6];
g[1]=v[15]*v[7];
g[2]=v[15]*v[8];
};
```

AceGen introduces auxiliary symbols and stores them in the array `v`.
In this example the elements at 6, 7, 8 and 15 of `v` are used.
I am wondering if there is a specific reason why the indices are not ascending from 0, and that there are unused entries in the auxiliary array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is code optimization that is done at several levels. With the
option "Mode"->"Plain"  (SMSInitialize["test", "Language" -> "C++", "Mode" -> "Plain"];) part of the optimization is suspended and the resulting code has fewer unused entries. It is also slower of course.

```
/******************* S U B R O U T I N E *********************/
void Test(double v[124],double u[3],double (*x),double (*L)
     ,double g[3])
{
v[1]=(*x);
v[2]=(*L);
v[3]=u[0];
v[4]=u[1];
v[5]=u[2];
v[6]=v[1]/v[2];
v[7]=1e0-v[1]/v[2];
v[8]=(v[1]*(1e0-v[1]/v[2]))/v[2];
v[9]=v[3]*v[6]+v[4]*v[7]+v[5]*v[8];
v[13]=2e0*v[8]*v[9];
v[12]=2e0*v[7]*v[9];
v[11]=2e0*v[6]*v[9];
v[10]=(v[9]*v[9]);
g[0]=v[11];
g[1]=v[12];
g[2]=v[13];
};
```